# Can I use multiple index.html with cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I configured cloudfront default root object `index.html`. Now when I am hitting the domain it's working fine

> example.com/

But when I am trying to access `index.html` present in the subdirectory i.e `test/index.html`

> example.com/test/index.html

I am getting error

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>TddZTBdPYdd5TKCdT</RequestId>
<HostId>UDr3K4KnfdKmnWBedzvdfgtlm4k5cRVbg4HbaMm4gWZ0qzzJzdd076UrfySFDfQgvlKnEEjfV1=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Can you show your S3 policy?